# Access-Control-Allow-Origin from localhost to online server

Tags: php, localhost, wildcard

I need to query a database on my online server from localhost. I know that I can use in my online server:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

I read that use a wild card is not so good. Considering that I'm gonna have around 100 different computers connecting from localhost to my online server, How can I do it to accomplish two things:

1. Make sure that just this computers can connect to my online server and avoid the wild card.
2. Find a way to set the localhost of every computer in a way that I don't need to depend on their IP or something that would require to add in the header ALL the IPs.

More info: the request comes from an app installed in a localhost with Xampp. From Localhost with Ajax request to a php file on the online server. Now that online server file has a wild card on the access-control. So, what should I put on the header (Access-Control-Allow-Origin) apart from the wild card. Should be something like http:localhost?

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: The origin doesn't identify the computers, it's the domain of the web page that's sending the AJAX requests.

Comment: You only need this if the web page is in a different domain from from the AJAX URL.

Comment: CORS has nothing to do with the IP addresses of the client machines. I suggest you go and read about how it works in more depth, as you seem to have misunderstood the concept somewhat. MDN has an excellent article about it

Comment: Barman, the request comes from an app installed in a localhost with Xampp. From Localhost with Ajax request to a php file on the online server. Now that online server file has a wild card on the access-control. So, what should I put on the header (Access-Control-Allow-Origin) apart from the wild card. Should be something like http:localhost?

Comment: Yes you can set localhost as the allowed origin, it's a valid origin. It would be `http://localhost` (unless your localhost applications use HTTPS)

Comment: P.s. it does seem strange to have separate copies of a web app all installed in 100 different local servers. Why not just run the app all from the one online server? That's kind of the whole point of a web application - it avoids you having to install and maintain lots of local applications on individual machines.

Comment: ADyson, because it use files over 1GB videos and images high resolution. So the database is online but all the files are local. With that runs fast and avoid to locate it on the cloud/server. And the database are online to secure the data of the app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set localhost as the allowed origin, it's a valid origin.

It would be `http://localhost` (unless your localhost applications use HTTPS)

Comment: Ok, ill try and let you know. Thanks

Comment: Yes! it worked! thanks! Just one more question. Setting the CORS, how can I do it to avoid the php file could be browsed. Because if I try a .htaccess file with deny All, CORS stops working.

Comment: you can't. If it's accessible via CORS, then it's accessible via any HTTP request. If you want to prevent casual browsing, you need to use some sort of authentication in the requests so that unauthorised requests can return an error.